# How to get current location in foreground in android?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location, locationlistener

I have  tried with IntentService but listener never is called (the same code in on activity works fines)

```
public class ISSubProcesoGps extends IntentService {
    // TODO: Rename actions, choose action names that describe tasks that this
    // IntentService can perform, e.g. ACTION_FETCH_NEW_ITEMS

    public static int hacambiado = 0;

    LocationManager lm;

    double longitude;
    double latitude;

    Location location = null;

    Criteria crit = new Criteria();


    public static volatile boolean shouldContinue = true;
    int contador = 0;




    // TODO: Rename parameters


    public ISSubProcesoGps() {

        super("ISSubProcesoGps");


    }

    /**
     * Starts this service to perform action Foo with the given parameters. If
     * the service is already performing a task this action will be queued.
     *
     * @see IntentService
     */


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent mIntent) {


        LocationManager lm;

        double longitude1;
        double latitude1;

        Location location = null;

        lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                latitude=location.getLatitude();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                String x =s;

            }
        };


        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener );


        latitude = 0;
        longitude = 0;


            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)  // the status icon
                    .setTicker("hola muy myintentservice")  // the status text
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())  // the time stamp
                    .setContentTitle("content title")  // the label of the entry
                    .setContentText("content teext")  // the contents of the entry
                    .setContentIntent(pendIntent)  // The intent to send when the entry is clicked
                    .build();

            startForeground(1, notification);

while(true)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    }


}
```

This code is in a button (in a fragment and it does work )

```
LocationManager lm;



Location location = null;

lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
}
LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        String x =s;

    }
};


lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener );
```

Problem is I need user can close the app and continues saving the location (battery is not a problem, the app is though in be connected all time)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `IntentService`, use `Service` and create `Instance variable` for `LocationListener` as LocationListener takes time to settle-up and start listening to location.